# Application crashes while reading an empty table in android

Tags: android, sqlite, indexoutofboundsexception

The issue is purely with the contents inside the tables. If the table is not empty (with one or more records), application works perfectly. I am deleting the contents of table and immediately after that reading the same table, it throws exception and app force closes.

I tried searching for it but couldn't conclude. The key point is : index out of bound exception which is thrown at movetofirst() method of cursor when i am going to read the table, i suppose... Please help.

```
public List<TableData> readForPaymentDetais()
    {
        List<TableData> paymentDetails = new ArrayList<TableData>();
        try
        {
            String selectQuery = "select * from PaymentDetails";
            SQLiteDatabase database = this.getWritableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = database.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            if(cursor.getCount() !=0)
            {
                if(cursor.moveToFirst())
                {
                    do
                    {
                        TableData data = new TableData();
                        data.setPaymentMade(Float.valueOf(cursor.getString(0).toString()));
                        data.setDateOfPayment(cursor.getString(1));

                        paymentDetails.add(data);               
                    }
                    while(cursor.moveToNext());
                }               
            }

            return paymentDetails;
        }
        catch(Exception exc)
        {
            return null;
        }       
    }
```

Comment: Can you post some code like the method for retrieving data from the database?

Comment: Log your exceptions instead of ignoring them in your `catch` block to learn what's wrong.

Comment: How to do that...?  Can you please explain? Although, while debugging, when the execution goes into catch block and if i try to watch the 'exc', it says 'error during evaluation'.

Answer (score 0):

Before executing moveToFirst method of cursor please check whether cursor is empty. For that you can use code like:

```
if (mCursor.getCount() == 0) {
    // cursor is empty
}
```

If cursor is not empty put your stuff in else part.

Comment: I tried this as well, but as soon as the execution comes to if(cursor.getCount()!=0) the next place it goes in the catch block directly. Even if i am checking the exception variable, it says 'error during evaluation'. i am not getting exactly what is needed. It is so simple in .net to read a database... i don't know why its behaving so strange in android... :(

Comment: Please add some code so that we can figure out the problem may be then you have some problem regarding cursor or before getting the count you might be manipulating the data so please add some code.

Comment: I have added the method. Kindly provide your inputs.

Comment: You have to use   `SQLiteDatabase database = this.getReadableDatabase();` instead.

Comment: I tried it with getReadableDatabase() too... Still the same exception occurs... :(

Comment: instead of "this" in  `this.getWritableDatabase();` use the name of the database activity which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` , because this will take the context of the present class. Try this.

Comment: Well.. Checking for == first instead of != did the trick... i still don't know why checking for != first was giving exceptions.. . :o