# How to prevent app crashed after delete empty database

Tags: android

i had been trying to prevent accidentally click on delete button when the data base is empty. It will crash after click.

Database handler

```
public void deleteLastMessage(Class a) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_MSG + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(a.get_message()) });
    db.close();
}
public String getLastString() {

    String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToLast();
    LastString = cursor.getString(0);
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    return LastString;
}
```

Activity

```
public void deleteMessage(View v) {
    LastMessage = new SubliminalClass(db.getLastString());
    db.deleteLastMessage(LastMessage);
```

It work fine when there are data to delete, it crashed when there is no data.
My data is a column of string.
Referred to this [Application crashes while reading an empty table in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30011426/application-crashes-while-reading-an-empty-table-in-android) but to no avail.

I have tried this below but still crashed when there is no data.

```
public boolean checkdb(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    Boolean rowExists;
    String nullString="";
    if (nullString.equals(getLastString())) //todo change this
        // DO SOMETHING WITH CURSOR
        rowExists = false;

    else
    {
        // I AM EMPTY
        rowExists = true;
    }
    return rowExists;
}
```

Anyone can help me solve this?

Comment: Any warnings? Error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Check the table `row count is greater than zero` then do the delete operation.

//Add in your activity

```
int rowCount = db.getRowCount();
    db.close();


if(rowCount>0)
{
db.deleteLastMessage(LastMessage);
}else{

}
```

//Add in DBhelperClass

```
public int getRowCount() {
    String countQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_NAME;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(countQuery, null);
    int cnt = cursor.getCount();
    cursor.close();
    return cnt;
}



public void deleteLastMessage(Class a) {
 try{
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_NAME, KEY_MSG + " = ?",
            new String[] { String.valueOf(a.get_message()) });
    db.close();
     } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: the if is always false,even if there are data in the database

Comment: fantastic!! that work perfectly. Thanks for your help. You are a life saver.

Answer (score 0):

You could add try/catch around your delete code.

Also the checkdb function could be like this

```
public boolean checkdb(){
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Log.d(TAG,"Got Readable DB")
    Cursor mCursor = db.rawQuery("SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME, null);
    Boolean rowExists = false;
    String nullString="";
    if(mCursor != null){
        Log.d(TAG,"Cursor is not null")
        try{
            rowExists = mCursor.getCount() > 0;
            Log.d(TAG,"rowExists is " + rowExists);
            mCursor.close();
        } catch (Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return rowExists;
}
```

Comment: still crashed when i click delete while there is no data

Comment: I have added logs in the above code can you execute the above code and paste the logs over here

Comment: couldn't log to binary event log: overflow.
Not supplying enough data to HAL, expected position 5746753 , only wrote 5594400
File error accessing recents directory (directory doesn't exist?).
Fatal error at this line
"Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToLast();"
And activity
"        LastMessage = new SubliminalClass(db.getLastString());"